# Verify Token from Keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I have a token which will be passed from a service to my Rest service. I want to use Spring security to validate the token against the public key (this is hosted on a different server). I have defined the Security Config class which is extending KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and i have implemented the httpSecurity and AuthenticationManager Builder.

I am using the OncePerRequestFilter and getting the Bearer token from the request.

@Component
public class JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");


    String token = null;

    if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        token = authorizationHeader.substring(7);

    }
```

}

What is the method to validate this token using Public Key with Keycloak classes?

Answer (score 0):

In order to configure your `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, I guess you're providing a [keycloak.json](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/adapters/oidc/spring-security/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/springsecurity/config/KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java#L58) file. In [this file](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/adapters/oidc/adapter-core/src/test/resources/keycloak.json), you are telling your application where your keycloak server authorization server url is: `auth-server-url`, optionally you could provide a `realm-public-key` as well ([this is not recommended](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/)). This is all you need, the adapter [will check](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/adapters/oidc/adapter-core/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/rotation/AdapterTokenVerifier.java#L101) for you that incoming tokens are signed by that server, for this realm.

**See also:**

- [Should I explicitly verify Keycloak token or this is done by Keycloak adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58389882/should-i-explicitly-verify-keycloak-token-or-this-is-done-by-keycloak-adapter)

Comment: I am not specifying the public key in my property files. As i mentioned the KID and other values get picked up from a different server. In my filter i am not sure what to do to include the authentication to pass. Right now whatever request i pass from my Postman it says Forbidden.